# android studio 3.0 Error:Could not resolve all files for configuration

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

**`android studio 3.0`** `error`

Error:Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.

> Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
>     Required by:
>         project :app
>   Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
>   Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.1.0/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.1.0/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.pom'.
>   Connect to dl.google.com:443 [dl.google.com/172.217.17.110] failed: Connection timed out: connect
>   Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
>   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.1.0/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.1.0/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.pom'.
>   Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/159.122.18.156] failed: Connection timed out: connect

Comment: Explain a little bit... Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Show your ```build.gradle``` file

Answer (score 3):

i was also facing this issue. place 'jcenter()' below the maven as shown below in project level gradle

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    jcenter()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This type of error occurs when there is a problem in version you compiled.

Go to your app level gradle.

Then find compile / dependencies section .

Replace

```
implementation 'com.android.support.appcompat_v7 ........'
```

With

```
implementation 'com.android.support.appcompat_v7:26.+'
```

There are many possible causes of error. Since you have provided very limited information, this might work

Comment: this is my build gradel //////   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.bok.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

Comment: buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

Comment: dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}

Comment: @abdo20122 did you try? If it worked say something so that others with similar problem can see later.